# How can I set coolbits nvidia Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia-prime

Ok, so it seems there is no longer a xorg.conf, so how do I get to set the coolbits option now?
I tried creating a config file automatically through nvidia-settings, but X fails if I do so. 
I have a nvidia optimus card btw...

Comment: I am in the same boat. Please report back here should you find a solution.. I'll do the same.

Comment: @MadHatter if you still looking for it, posted how I did it in my case, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ubuntu MATE 18.04 possible solution is to edit config in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, namely file `10-nvidia.conf`. Here is how it looks in my case for example:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "Coolbits" "12"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

I just installed nvidia-prime via **Additional Drivers** GUI and then edited this file to add Coolbits option and it worked with no issues.

I assume it should work the same for main branch of Ubuntu.

I edit my input options using file `40-libinput.conf` in same directory as well.

Comment: Worked, thanks :) 
I set the Coolbits to "255" though.

Comment: @Szpaqn yeah, this post is ~2 years old, so some values are likely different due to system updates, different drivers etc.

Answer (score 2):

That was a good answer, but I think things have become slightly easier.

Unless you have some kind of custom xorg configuration you can just run this command.

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=8
```

Your cool-bits number will likely vary depending on your graphics card.  GreenWithEnvy gave me mine although not sure if it is accurate so double check.  It is an Nvidia graphics card monitoring and overclocking software.  If you haven't heard of it.  You can find it on FlatHub.